# Can I pop an element from position n in a slice using a one-liner?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I was going through the [slice tricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks) document and saw some one-liners to pop and pop front. For example, these two work fine:

```golang
// pop
s := []int{1, 2, 3}     
last, s := s[len(s)-1], s[:len(s)-1]    
fmt.Println(last, s) // Prints 3 [1 2]
```

```golang
// pop front
s := []int{1, 2, 3}     
first, s := s[0], s[1:]                 
fmt.Println(first, s)  // Prints 1 [2 3]
```

But if I try doing something like this to pop the second element:

```golang
s := []int{1, 2, 3}     
second, s := s[1], append(s[0:1], s[2:]...)
fmt.Println(second, s) // Prints 3 [1 3]
```

It pops the second element but the `second` variable points to the second element from the new slice. Why does that happen for this case but not for the first two? In order to work I have to use separate lines:

```golang
s := []int{1, 2, 3}                     
second := s[1]          
s = append(s[0:1], s[2:]...)
fmt.Println(second, s) // Prints 2 [1 3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Go spec section on assignments](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) tells us that this is the

> second form

of *tuple assignment*.  It goes on to say:

> The assignment proceeds in two phases. First, the operands of [index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) and [pointer indirections](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) (including implicit pointer indirections in [selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)) on the left and the expressions on the right are all [evaluated in the usual order](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation). Second, the assignments are carried out in left-to-right order.

So the compiler computes that `second` and `s` are to be assigned by evaluating them for assignment purposes—which just produces their names, more or less<sup>1</sup>—and also evaluates the right hand side expressions in

> the usual order

which means we must go look at what "the usual order" means, by following the link.  This gets us to [Order of evaluation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation).

The text here is a bit tricky, but the *example* is quite instructive:

> in the (function-local) assignment
>
> ```
> y[f()], ok = g(h(), i()+x[j()], <-c), k()
> ```
>
> the function calls and communication happen in the order `f()`, `h()`, `i()`, `j()`, `<-c`, `g()`, and `k()`. However, the order of those events compared to the evaluation and indexing of `x` and the evaluation of `y` is not specified.

Let's compare this to your own expression:

> ```
> second, s := s[1], append(s[0:1], s[2:]...)
> ```

We know that `append` will be called before ... well, we're not really sure: there are no further (right-of-the-call) function calls or channel invocations.  But clearly it has to be called before `s` can be assigned-into.

At the same time, though, the order of this call with respect to the "evaluation and indexing of" `s[1]` is explicitly not specified.  If it's done *first*, the `append` operation will (potentially<sup>2</sup>) modify-in-place the array that backs the slice `s[0:1]`.

What is clearly happening, then, is that `append(s[0:1], s[2:]...)` is in fact modifying the array in place.  Then the evaluation and indexing `s[1]` occurs, with the array modified.  This fetches the modified value of `s[1]` and copies it to the variable `second`.

> Why does that happen for this case but not for the first two?

Those do not call `append` and hence do not allow `append` to modify the array in place.

---

<sup>1</sup>Due to the use of SSA internally, these become assignments to *new* variables, as it were, but it all works out the same in the end.

<sup>2</sup>It is up to the `append` function to decide whether to do this in-place modification, or to create a new backing array.  In this case, though, since we're shrinking the overall length, it's clearly going to be *possible*, and the actual implementation takes advantage of this every time—though that is not specified either!

---

#### Conclusion

The thing to do here is to write a tiny function that does the extract-and-update, not as a one-liner, and simply allow the compiler to inline it into something reasonably fast.  Of course, that makes us wish for generics and hence Go 2.